# calling php function in echo function

Tags: php

I am new to PHP and I have a problem getting an output. I have to declare and define a  function named `writeName` and within it echo out: "Avril". When I call the function, the output should be `My name is Avril`.

Here is my code:

```
<?php
function writeName() {
  echo "Avril";
}
echo "My name is" . writeName() . "<br>";
?>
```

My current output: `AvrilMy name is`

My desired output: `My name is Avril`

Comment: `echo "Avril";` > `return "Avril";`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
<?php
function writeName() {
   return "Avril";
}
echo "My name is " . writeName() . "<br>";
?>
```

Answer (score 0):

Your function is doing output. But you're trying to use it as if it RETURNED the `Avril` name.

The execution sequence is:

```
parse writeName function
parse echo
    find string "my name is"
    execute function writeName
        output "Avril"
    find "<br>"
build echo with "my name is" and "br"
output "my name is <br>"
```

What you should have is'

```
function getName() {
   return "Avril";
}

echo "My name is " . getName() . "<br>";
```

This makes the execution sequence:

```
parse echo
   find string "my name is"
   find function getName()
      execute getName()
         return "Avril"
    find string "Avril"
    find string "<br>"
    build string "My name is Avril<br>"
output string
```